# Unity GoogleVR1.2 Cardboard displays upside down on Samsung

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, samsung-mobile, google-vr, google-vr-sdk

Currently, I am trying to make the Virtual Tour app to play with cardboard, then get the demo completed and it's working like a charm in Editor Play mode and on my Lenovo Phab 2 phone. Unfortunately, when I install it on Samsung Note 9, the app displays upside down. I have tried change the orientation in player setting and edit the android manifest but still no luck are there any one know the solution? or is it the bug in GoogleVRSDK or Unity ,caused at first there is the lack in app build that Unity build the app as normal app not Cardboard one even GoogleVR Demo scene, but after restart Unity it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

This is apparently an issue with Unity 2019.1.x and both Android and iOS.

1. Either, switch rendering from Vulkan to OpenGLES3 (Android, not sure about iOS)
2. Or, downgrade to 2018.3.14f (is said to work for both iOS and Android)

Track updates here:

https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-unity-sdk/issues/1030
https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-unity-sdk/issues/1031